# R: dplyr::bind_rows() operating on lists?

Tags: r, dplyr

It is my understanding that dplyr::bind_rows() only operates on data frames. Why are both of the below identical?

```
# Load pkgs, set seed
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1) 

# Create toy data
foo <- list(df1 = data.frame(A = rnorm(3), B = rnorm(3)),
            df2 = data.frame(C = rnorm(3), B = rnorm(3)),
            df3 = data.frame(C = rnorm(3), A = rnorm(3)))

df1 <- bind_rows(foo)


# Combine all sources into 1 source
for (i in 1:(length(foo) - 1)){
  foo[[i+1]] <- dplyr::bind_rows(foo[[i]], foo[[i+1]])
}

# Extract final df from list
df2 <- foo[[length(foo)]]

# Check for identical
identical(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Why would you expect them to be different? You are essentially binding the current dataframe to the next dataframe at every iteration; which is the same thing as binding all dataframes all at once.

Comment: ?bind_rows appears to suggest this is only meant for data frames. So, I was not expecting to be able to use it with the entire list. Furthermore, if it was applied to the entire list, I wasn't sure why it would know to iterate across all elements of the list...

Comment: `bind_rows` will combine data frames into a single data frame, regardless of whether the data frames are separate objects or part of a list. Compare: `bind_rows(mtcars[1:5, ], iris[1:6, ], mtcars[6:8, ])` and `bind_rows(list(mtcars[1:5, ], iris[1:6, ], mtcars[6:8, ]))`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/bind.html

"Each argument can either be a data frame, a list that could be a data frame, or a list of data frames."

```
bind_rows(foo)
```

passes a "a list of data frames."

While

```
bind_rows(foo[[i]], foo[[i+1]])
```

passes data frames.

Incidentally, you can't pass `rbind` a list of data frames, which is why you would have had to use

```
do.call(rbind, foo)
```